# word/phrase/term to refer to a teaching approach

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

Some teachers intentionally slow down their speech to let students hear them clearly. Meanwhile, they keep the contraction to let students learn the pronunciation point.

For example, when speaking slowly, "an apple" would be pronounced `/æn . ˈæpəl/`. When speaking slow in a teaching way, the phrase would be pronounced `/ən . ˈnæpəl/`.

How do I refer to this kind of teaching technique/tip/approach?

Comment: I very much doubt that there is a word for this.  Does a word or expression exist in your language?

Comment: @JamesK I've never heard of something like that in my language.

Comment: You did well explaining it. If you want a single word with that meaning, then you might have to invent one.

Comment: Teachers articulate well, or should. An apple doesn't have a contraction. doesn't is a contraction.

Comment: Why would you say "an napple"? Who does that? I don't think that's a usual or helpful way of speaking even in education. If you've just made this up then obviously there's not going to be a word for it.

Comment: Actually, this is called connected speech in linguistics. You don't learn contractions for pronunciation. You learn them because English uses them.

Comment: The generic term for the adjustments made to the volume, tone, and pace of your voice in order to make your message accessible to a specific audience is __voice modulation__.

Answer (score 0):

You could write, "In language learning a common pedagogical approach involves  ***enunciating*** each word slowly and separately.

Perhaps, "[enunciate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/enunciate)" is the word you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't quite work.  Enunicate would mean "an ... apple"  not "an .. napple"

Answer (score 0):

Most Americans call the technique, "going slow".

For example,

> STUDENT: "I don't understand why that works. Can you ***go slow*** for me?"
>
> TEACHER: "Yes. I will ***go slowly*** this time."